# how to have same path for multiple component with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, connected-react-router

I use react-router 5x..., i search to have the same path but with multiple component, something like

```
<Route path={"/"} component={App & SeachFlow} />
```

in my tsx i have

```
export default (
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path="/" component={SeachFlow} />
  </Route>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this notation if you want to display both components:

```
<Route path={"/"}>
  <App/>
  <SearchFlow/>
</Route>
```

Comment: in my tsx file, SearchFlow don't seem to be know like that

Comment: is it a component?

Comment: yes, i edited  the initial post